Want to get data from native android shared preferences
I don’t want to use method or event channel.
I am using the shared_preferences plugin in Flutter and want to access data from Android native shared preferences in Flutter code.
Here is my understanding:
1.Flutter uses shared_preferences to create a FlutterSharedPreference.xml file, while Android uses myprefs.xml.
I would like to retrieve data from Android native shared preferences within my Flutter code.

flutter add “flutter.” prefix in the key

Is there any way to get data or only create single file instead of 2 different.
